# ExcelJs. Парсинг xlsx. Где искать темы на которые ссылаются стили ячеек?

Tags: javascript, excel

```
// fill
{
    "type": "pattern",
    "pattern": "solid",
    "fgColor": {
        "theme": 3,
        "tint": -0.249977111117893
    },
    "bgColor": {
        "indexed": 64
    }
}
// font
{
    "bold": true,
    "size": 11,
    "color": {
        "theme": 0
    },
    "name": "Calibri",
    "family": 2,
    "charset": 204,
    "scheme": "minor"
}
```